# "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" error in Braintree

Tags: asp.net, ssl, payment-gateway, braintree, tls1.2

In my local PC Braintree showing error "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" when executing :

```
 var clientToken = gateway.ClientToken.generate();
```

I am using "Braintree-2.33.0.dll" and my target .net version is 4.5.1. 
I have enabled TLS 1.2.

It was working nicely three days ago. But suddenly started showing error. Many people faced same error and most of then have changed the **SecurityProtocol**. I dont find any way to change that from braintree. Is there any way to change

> ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol

for braintree ? or anything else I am missing or need to do ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You need to update the [.NET Braintree SDK](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_dotnet) you're using to at least [version 3.1.0](https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update/tree/master/Braintree#net), the minimum version that supports TLS 1.2. Once compelete, you can validate your setup using the steps [here](https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update#net).

On [December 13, 2016](https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/updating-your-production-environment-to-support-tlsv1-2/), Braintree transitioned sandbox to only accept requests made using TLS 1.2+. After June 30th, 2017, Braintree will no longer officially support any requests in the production environment below TLS 1.2.

Comment: I'm using Braintree 3.5 and getting this error in Sandbox. Do I have to change something in Web.config? - Scratch that, 3.5 was my js version, 3.0 was my SDK version. Upgrading.

Comment: yes, it's wide issue; only lib updating did not resolve it; got same on 01.01.2017 with Sandbox; looks like tls 1.3 must be enabled or install on server, etc or maybe additional server configs needed; (maybe ms added some bad security fixes, etc);

Comment: still try resolve that issue, prev. used lib. 2.27;  can said it's very bad, at least braintry should notify users about that changes via emails etc,  now I am little confused and don't known if my Production workable or not; and if it will broken on 31..01.2017 or not;

Comment: Did any of you find a solution? I'm experiencing the very same. I have to say, this is a rather poorly announced change on Braintree's part.

Comment: Some NuGet messery later, updated to 3.5 and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Setting this anywhere in your `program.cs` or `startup.cs` worked for me, even on versions greater than 3.1:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```