# Could not load file or assembly "Braintree" or one of its dependencies

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, visual-studio-2015, braintree

So the Braintree Sandbox now only uses TLS 1.2, and much like hasnayn in [this forum question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158356/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-error-in-brai), after running into the issue, realized I needed the latest Braintree SDK.

So I've downloaded the DLL (File version 3.0.0.0, Product version 3.3.0), updated my project to .NET 4.5.2, removed the previous DLL from my production DLL project, and added the new one, but now **I'm getting this error when trying to call any Braintree function:**

> Could not load file or assembly 'Braintree, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31b586f34d3e96c7' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I scoured the internet for a couple days now, even trying other DLL releases, and I get the same result, with no hint as to the issue.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the name of the dll that you added as reference.
Is it Braintree-net452.dll or Braintree.dll ?
When I add Braintree-net452.dll (from https://github.com/braintree/braintree_dotnet/releases/) and build the project, I don't see that dll being copied to bin. However, if I rename the dll to just Braintree.dll, it copies over.,,

Comment: It's "Braintree-net452.dll"

Comment: Try renaming to just Braintree.dll as my earlier comment. It should work and it works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming the braintree dll to just Braintree.dll. If the file name is Braintree-net452.dll, it doesn't copy to bin folder for some reason.

Comment: Wow... that worked. That was a disappointingly obvious and simple solution. I'm a little upset that this wasn't made clear in the documentation --unless I missed something. Who expects you have to rename a DLL from download to make it work. Thanks so much! +1